# Loading large set of images kill the process

Tags: numpy, image-processing, keras, computer-vision, numpy-ndarray

Loading 1500 images of size `(1000,1000,3)` breaks the code and throughs `kill 9` without any further error. Memory used before this line of code is **16%** of system total memory. Total size of images direcotry is **7.1G**.

```
X = np.asarray(images).astype('float64')
y = np.asarray(labels).astype('float64')
```

system spec is:

- OS: macOS Catalina
- processor: 2.2 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7 16 GB 2
- memory: 16 GB 2400 MHz DDR4

Update: 
getting the bellow error while running the code on 32 vCPUs, 120 GB memory.

`MemoryError: Unable to allocate 14.1 GiB for an array with shape (1200, 1024, 1024, 3) and data type float32`

Comment: Do you get the same error if you set .astype(np.float32) ?

Comment: A quick calculation shows you are trying to load 36 GB of data. Obviously that won’t fit in 16 GB of memory. Note that the images on disk are compressed, and therefore occupy less space.

Comment: @CrisLuengo running it on 120Gb memory machine yet fails.

Comment: Do you maybe have a 32-bit version of Python?

Comment: @CrisLuengo it is 64.

Comment: Does the virtual machine have access to all 120 GB RAM? They can be configured so as to limit the amount of memory accessible to a process. Other than that I don’t know why a 64-bit version of Python would fail to allocate a 14 GB array.

Comment: @CrisLuengo it should have access to most of it. However, I kinda tackle my problem by reducing batch size, reducing images size, and train the model on multiple shuffled input size of 1000 images. it is giving reasonable result.

Comment: It's probably not necessary to store the images as floats, since the data itself it probably unsigned integers. That should decrease your memory load.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to provide some more info/details for an exact answer but, assuming that this is a memory error(incredibly likely, size of the images on disk does not represent the size they would occupy in memory, so that is irrelevant. In 100% of all cases, the images in memory will occupy a lot more space due to pointers, objects that are needed and so on. Intuitively I would say that 16GB of ram is nowhere nearly enough to load 7GB of images. It's impossible to tell you how much you would need but from experience I would say that you'd need to bump it up to 64GB. If you are using Keras, I would suggest looking into the [DirectoryIterator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/DirectoryIterator).

Edit:

As Cris Luengo pointed out, I missed the fact that you stated the size of the images.

Comment: OP gives enough information in the question to allow you to compute exactly how much memory those images will occupy: 1500 images, 1000x1000x3 values each, 8 bytes each value. Comes out to 36 GB, as I said in my comment.

Comment: Yup, somehow I didn't register the `(1000, 1000, 3)` part, correct. Thanks! Edited.